# What is the analogous function to DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml(query) for json is the query is a variable and with oracle 19?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556656/what-is-the-analogous-function-to-dbms-xmlgen-getxmlquery-for-json) because the given answer works only if the query isn't a variable.

the following query is working but the result is saved in a xml file.

```
SELECT XMLTYPE.createXML (DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml ('select  2 as a from dual')) FROM DUAL;
```

It's working but I can use macro only in oracle>19. (because of the macro)

```
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
  query VARCHAR2(100) := 'select 1 a from dual';
  ret   VARCHAR2(100) := chr(13) || query || chr(13);
BEGIN
  RETURN ret;
END;
SELECT JSON_ARRAYagg(      json_object(t.*)  )
  FROM     f_test() t
```

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=52dd11538342f359cb51abfbf2ea4b3e)

I've tried to use dynamic sql with oracle 19

```
WITH
    FUNCTION f
        RETURN JSON_ARRAY
    IS
        query   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'select 1 from dual';
        l_str   VARCHAR2 (1000);
        l_cnt   JSON_ARRAY;
    BEGIN
        l_str :=
               'with from_dynamic_query as ('
            || query
            || ') SELECT JSON_ARRAYagg(      json_object(*)  ) from from_dynamic_query';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
            INTO l_cnt;

        RETURN l_cnt;
    END;
SELECT 
  FROM DUAL;
```

> [Error] Execution (20: 8): ORA-06553: PLS-313: 'F' not declared in this scope
> ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Item ignored
> ORA-06553: PLS-488: 'JSON_ARRAY' must be a type

Comment: Looks like the issue is not related to absence of SQL_MACRO, but inability of `json_object` to serialize `t.*`. Because in this particular case SQL_MACRO is just a way to translate a string to executable query. This may be achieved by local function declaration (`with function`) and `execute immediate` with `json_object` embedded into the query. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6d570bafd5bd77071bc23f7300cd506d)

Comment: @astentx Yes you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, the issue may not be related to `SQL_MACRO`, but inability to process `*` in `json_object` (see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6d570bafd5bd77071bc23f7300cd506d) in 18c).

But this may also be worked out with [Polymorphic Table Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_TF.html), which are available in 18c. You need to define new output calculated column with a row value serialized into JSON.

Below is the code example:

> ```
> create package pkg_ser as
>   /*Package to implement PTF*/
>
>   function describe(
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   ;
>   
>   procedure fetch_rows;
> end pkg_ser;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create package body pkg_ser as
>
>   function describe(
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   as
>   begin
>     /*Mark input columns as used for subsequent row processing*/
>     for i in 1..tab.column.count loop
>       tab.column(i).for_read := TRUE;
>     end loop;
>     
>     /*Declare json output column*/
>     return dbms_tf.describe_t(
>       new_columns => dbms_tf.columns_new_t(
>         1 => dbms_tf.column_metadata_t(
>           name => 'JSONVAL',
>           type => dbms_tf.type_varchar2
>         )
>       )
>     );
>   end;
>   
>   procedure fetch_rows
>   /*Process rowset and serialize each row in JSON*/
>   as
>     rowset dbms_tf.row_set_t;
>     num_rows pls_integer;
>     new_col dbms_tf.tab_varchar2_t;
>   begin
>     /*Get rows*/
>     dbms_tf.get_row_set(
>       rowset => rowset,
>       row_count => num_rows
>     );
>     
>     for rn in 1..num_rows loop
>       /*Calculate new column value in the same row*/
>       new_col(rn) := dbms_tf.row_to_char(
>         rowset => rowset,
>         rid => num_rows,
>         format => dbms_tf.FORMAT_JSON
>       );
>     end loop;
>     
>     /*Put column to output*/
>     dbms_tf.put_col(
>       columnid => 1,
>       collection => new_col
>     );
>   end;
> end pkg_ser;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create function f_serialize_json(tab in table)
> /*Function to serialize into JSON using PTF*/
> return table pipelined
> row polymorphic using pkg_ser;
> /
> ```

> ```
> with function f_local_exec (
>   query in clob
> ) return varchar2
> as
>   ret varchar2(32000);
> begin
>   /*Translate string to query using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE*/
>   execute immediate '
>     with a as (
>       ' || query || '
>     )
>     select json_arrayagg(jsonval format json)
>     from f_serialize_json(a)
>   ' into ret;
>   
>   return ret;
> end;
>
> select f_local_exec(
>   'select level as id, mod(level, 3) as val from dual connect by level < 10'
> ) as jsonval
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | JSONVAL                                                                                                                                                             |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | [{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0},{"ID":9, "VAL":0}] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=701aab8ec20a16115d6a963d0a6cf66d)*

Answer (score 0):

It works if I replace json_arry with clob

```
WITH
    FUNCTION f
        RETURN clob
    IS
        query   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'select 1 a from dual';
        l_str   VARCHAR2 (1000);
        l_cnt   clob;
    BEGIN
        l_str :=
               'with from_dynamic_query as ('
            || query
            || ') SELECT JSON_ARRAYagg(      json_object(*)  ) from from_dynamic_query';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
            INTO l_cnt;

        RETURN l_cnt;
    END;
SELECT f()
  FROM DUAL;
```